# Jax rs contollers set limit of upload file size

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jax-rs

I have Spring boot service with jax-rs controllers. I need to limit upload file size. All spring's properties don't work because jax-rs don't use them.

I am using config to enable multipart loading

```
register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

I can upload files via controller. Now i want to limit file size.
I try to use `MultipartConfigElement` like this:

```
@Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*")
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, IBankJerseyConfig.class.getName())
        registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(null, 10000L, -1, 0))
        registration
    }
```

Now when try to load file that exceed limit i get `Stream closed` error. But when i load files that not exceed limit i get `Bad request 400` .

I can load files with any size successfully when i use these config:

```
@Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*")
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, IBankJerseyConfig.class.getName())
        registration
    }
```

Please help me to limit file size for jax-rs controllers in spring boot.

Comment: How are you sending the request? Are you sure you're sending a proper multipart request?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha i am sending standard Postman multipart request. THis request works properly when  i don't set MultipartConfig for  ServletRegistrationBean.

Comment: See what happens if you [use other values beside the default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64868993/2587435)